Trouble displaying a list of movies corresponding to each genre in ASP.NET Core MVC web application
I'm working on an ASP.NET Core MVC web application using C# and Entity Framework. I have a Movie class with a GenreId property, and a Genre class with an Id property. I'm trying to display a list of movies for each genre on a web page.
Here's what I have so far:
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
    // Other movie properties
}

public class Genre
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Genre1 { get; set; }
    // Other genre properties
}

I've tried using the following method in my GenreRepository to get movies for a specific genre:
public IQueryable<Movie> GetGenresWithMovies(int genreId)
{
    return _dbContext.Movies.Where(x => x.GenreId == genreId);
}

I've tried using the following method in my GenreViewmodel:
private GenreRepository _repo;
public List<Genre> GenreList { get; set; }// property
public List<Movie> MoviesList { get; set; }//property
public Movie CurrentMovie { get; set; }//property
public Genre CurrentGenre { get; set; } //property
public bool IsActionSuccess { get; set; }//property

public GenresViewModel(MovieDbContext context) //constructor
{
    _repo = new GenreRepository(context);
    GenreList = GetAllGenres();
    CurrentGenre = GenreList.FirstOrDefault();
    MoviesList = GetMoviesByGenreId(CurrentGenre.Id);
}

public List<Movie> GetMoviesByGenreId(int genreid) //method
{
    return _repo.GetMoviesByGenreId(genreid).ToList();
}

However, I'm encountering issues with data retrieval. The GetGenresWithMovies method is not fetching data correctly.
I'm seeking guidance on how to modify this method or approach to effectively display a list of movies corresponding to each genre on my web page.
Additionally, I'm open to alternative approaches or suggestions on how to achieve this functionality efficiently and effectively.
Thank you for your assistance!

You haven't stated what the problem is.

A view model that has a reference to a repository is highly suspect.

That's not how a view model is supposed to work.

Hello have you tried the solution provided? Did you able to made any progress on this?

Yes, this helped and I was able to figure it out. thank you so much?


I'm encountering issues with data retrieval. The GetGenresWithMovies
method is not fetching data correctly.

Well, according to your shared code snippet along with the scenario, I think the issue with your current approach lies in how you're fetching movies in the GenresViewModel constructor. Because, the method GetGenresWithMovies in the GenreRepository was expected to return genres with their associated movies, but its implementation was only filtering movies by genre ID.
Instead of doing that, here is the way, how I have investigate your scenario and fetched the Movie and Genres.
Demo View Model:
public class MovieWithGenreViewModel
{
    public string MovieTitle { get; set; }
    public string GenreName { get; set; }
}

Demo Data:
I haven't use the DbContext, instead used the static list of your given model. But you can use your context.
private static List<Genre> Genres = new List<Genre>
{
    new Genre { Id = 1, Name = "Action" },
    new Genre { Id = 2, Name = "Comedy" },
    new Genre { Id = 3, Name = "Drama" },
    new Genre { Id = 4, Name = "Horror" },
    new Genre { Id = 5, Name = "Science Fiction" },
};

private static List<Movie> Movies = new List<Movie>
{
    new Movie { Id = 1, Title = "Die Hard", GenreId = 1 },
    new Movie { Id = 2, Title = "Mad Max: Fury Road", GenreId = 1 },
    new Movie { Id = 3, Title = "The Hangover", GenreId = 2 },
    new Movie { Id = 4, Title = "Superbad", GenreId = 2 },
    new Movie { Id = 5, Title = "The Shawshank Redemption", GenreId = 3 },
    new Movie { Id = 6, Title = "Forrest Gump", GenreId = 3 },
    new Movie { Id = 7, Title = "The Conjuring", GenreId = 4 },
    new Movie { Id = 8, Title = "Get Out", GenreId = 4 },
    new Movie { Id = 9, Title = "Inception", GenreId = 5 },
    new Movie { Id = 10, Title = "The Matrix", GenreId = 5 },
};

Controller:
I have directly executed the test code within the controller action. You could do the same stuff within your repository.
public ActionResult Index(int? genreId = null, string genreName = null)
{

    var filteredGenres = Genres.AsQueryable();
    var filteredMovies = Movies.AsQueryable();

   
    if (genreId.HasValue)
    {
        filteredMovies = filteredMovies.Where(m => m.GenreId == genreId.Value);
    }

    
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(genreName))
    {
        var genre = Genres.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Name.Equals(genreName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        if (genre != null)
        {
            filteredMovies = filteredMovies.Where(m => m.GenreId == genre.Id);
        }
    }

    var viewModel = filteredMovies
    .Select(movie => new MovieWithGenreViewModel
    {
        MovieTitle = movie.Title,
        GenreName = Genres.FirstOrDefault(genre => genre.Id == movie.GenreId) != null
            ? Genres.FirstOrDefault(genre => genre.Id == movie.GenreId).Name
            : "Unknown"
    }).ToList();

    return View(viewModel);
}

Note: I have both used genreId and genreName to filter Genres, you could consider your scenario and requirement.
View:
@model List<MovieWithGenreViewModel>

<h2>Movies and Their Genres</h2>

<form asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="genreName">Search by Genre Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="genreName" name="genreName" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
</form>

<table class="table mt-3">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Movie Title</th>
            <th>Genre</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var movie in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@movie.MovieTitle</td>
                <td>@movie.GenreName</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

Output:


Note: When you would use above example witin your scenario, just replace the static list with your DbContext. Please refer to this official document for more example.
